# How to reliably manage a phoenix app with upstart

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, phoenix-framework

I've just recently updated my phoenix application to 0.16.0. And I am following the docs related to [deployment](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.16.0/docs/advanced-deployment#section-setting-up-our-web-server).

Everything has gone relatively smoothly until now. The phoenix docs tell you to setup a upstart script as such:

```
description "test phoenix app"

## Uncomment the following two lines to run the
## application as www-data:www-data
setuid phoenix
setgid phoenix

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

expect stop
respawn

env MIX_ENV=prod
export MIX_ENV

## Uncomment the following two lines if we configured
## our port with an environment variable.
#env PORT=8888
#export PORT

## Add app HOME directory.
env HOME="/home/phoenix"
export HOME


pre-start exec /bin/sh /test_app/bin/test_app start

post-stop exec /bin/sh /test_app/bin/test_app stop
```

This script succeeds in starting the application, but when I run 
`initctl stop phoenix` upstart tells me it has stopped phoenix, but after running a `ps aux|grep phoenix` I can see that the application is still very much running and the server is still returning 200 at localhost:4000.

I'm perplexed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'm adding this as an answer.

I think the issue here is that the following line

```
pre-start exec /bin/sh /test_app/bin/test_app start
```

is spawning processes which are not under control of upstart. Instead, try the following line instead:

```
 pre-start exec /bin/sh /test_app/bin/test_app foreground
```

This should ensure that the spawned processes still belong to upstart. You should then be able to stop it normally.